# Scatterplot disappears on deck.gl multiple layer chart on Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

While using the deck.gl multiple layer chart I am facing an issue, I'm using a dataset with one geojson column containing a multi polygon and other columns with longitudes and latitudes pointing on that particular multi polygon. With that dataset, I created a polygon in the deck.gl geojson chart and a scatterplot as well. the issue is when I plot these two in the deck.gl multiple layers it shows both charts at zoom level 1 to 2.1, but at 2.2 the scatter plot points disappear. I have also attached screenshots of how it acts with different zoom levels and the result of just scatterplot at zoom level 5. < Images Attached>

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP53B.png)  [Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOgo.png)  [Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8b7E.png)  [MultipleLayer Zoom Level 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UllOZ.png)  [MultipleLayer Zoom Level 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8jXd.png)  [MultipleLayer Zoom Level 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zl3E.png)  [Removing Polygon from multiple layer at zoom level 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djaH3.png)

I want to use Apache superset to re-create this type of
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gEHn.jpg)